# How to calculate Vuex states difference without triggering reactivity

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have list of components which changes Vuex state after click.
And i want to render difference between two Vuex state values: before and after action dispatched from click handler.

It could be something like that:

```html
<template>
<ul>
  <li v-for="item of items" @click="clickItem">{{difference}}</li>
</ul>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
              difference() {
                  let oldValue = this.$store.getters.getValue();
                  this.$store.dispatch(SOME_ACTION);
                  let newValue = this.$store.getters.getValue();
                  this.$store.dispatch(UNDO_SOME_CATION);
                  return newValue-oldValue;
              }
              clickItem() {
                  this.$store.dispatch(SOME_ACTION);
              }
        }
    }
</script>
```

But the problem is that this code produce infinite rendering loop because action dispatching changes Vuex store and Vuex reactivity 
in turn triggering app components rerendering.

Is there any possibility disable Vuex reactivity than dispatch action, get new value, than dispatch undo action and enable reactivity? If yes, it could solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but my idea is to have `difference` return it's functionality from an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), then add a flag for whether it's been dispatched or not.

```
const difference = (function() {
  let dispatched;

  return function() {
    if (dispatched) {
      dispatched = false;
      return;
    }

    let oldValue = this.$store.getters.getValue();
    this.$store.dispatch(SOME_ACTION);
    dispatched = true;

    let newValue = this.$store.getters.getValue();
    this.$store.dispatch(UNDO_SOME_CATION);
    return newValue-oldValue;
  }
})()
```

Comment: It's working idea and i have tried this. 
But there is big performance loss for reactivity. It's very slow if you have large amount of components.

Comment: Visual, by console.time, and by DevTool performance tab. The time it takes to render "page" with ~60 components increased from milliseconds(without difference calculation) to ~3 seconds. 
It isn't a problem with you code. it's problem with my complex store, components organization and vuex reactivity.
You logic resolve problem with infinite loop.
I think, i should change my question to clarify that the problem is not only the infinite loop.